# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF and URI's

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am having some trouble loading a model supplied by a colleague in rviz.  For my own interests, I wish to be able to load a urdf which is not part of a ros package.  Thus, everywhere where it was written:

```
 <mesh filename="package://derp/meshes/zmp.stl" />
```

I replaced with:

```
 <mesh filename="file://home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl" />
```

and then afterwards

```
 <mesh filename="file:///home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl" />
```

Well both of those didn't work, I still got the following errors:

```
[ERROR] [1323810997.737214696]: Error retrieving file [/home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl]:  malformed
[ERROR] [1323810997.737386409]: Could not load model 
     '/home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl' for link 'zmp': OGRE 
     EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource  
     /home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl in resource group 
     Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /tmp/buildd/ros-
     electric-visualization-common-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-visualization-
     common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-
     3/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
```

Could anyone give me some tips on what I am doing wrong?  A link to expanded documentation would be great as well, the Resource Retriever page is quite empty.  Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12331/urdf-and-uri%27s/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-12-14**:
Oh my, I hope I didn't forget to update my robot_description parameter with the new xml... Let me try again.

**Comment by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) on 2011-12-13**:
The "Error retrieving file [/home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/data/cRoNA/meshes/zmp.stl]:  malformed" line looks like you actually specified "". The file:// prefix seems to be mandatory though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is a bug in urdf_parser that prevents it from opening files specified by a file:// URL. I filed a bug report: [ticket 5297](http://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5297)

After applying the patch I posted there, I can load URDFs with file:// paths into rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3